# How can I remove malicious data from an HttpRequest so that it is not returned by an HttpResponse?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, xss, windows-server-2003

I have to prevent a Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability from being sent in an HttpResponse from  data in the HttpRequest header to pass a webapp assessment.

For example, HttpRequest Header:

```
GET /%22%20%73%54%79%4c%65%3d%58%3a%65%58%2f%2a%2a%2f%70%52%65%53%73%49%6f%4e%28% 61%6c%65%72%74%28%35%37%31%33%35%29%29%20%22 HTTP/1.1
```

HttpResponse Location Value:

```
/" sTyLe=X:eX/**/pReSsIoN(%?3e3ea140
```

My site is an ASP.Net website written in VB.Net running on Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0.  What are my options?  Do I have to use ISAPI filters in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do this is to make sure your data in database (or whatever source you’re using) is clean and also to make sure you’re validating all user input on the server side.

Once you confirm your data is clean and that all input is being validated you should be safe.

Not sure if there are any built in ways in IIS.

Comment: My issue is not in validating input going through my web application to the database, but in filtering the http requests and/or http responses for malicious data going to/from the server.